Can a restaurant make me pay 18% tip in the US
I just came back from a trip in the US and a lot of restaurants automatically added 18% tip to the check (it specifically says “tip”/“gratuity”)
From where I come from it is common to tip voluntarily and it’s super rude to just add this charge without telling you.
There were couple of restaurants that their menu stated that if we are a party of more than 4 we will have to pay 18% tip, but we were only 2 people and they still charged us.
So My question is:
Am I legally allowed to give lower amount than 18% when i see that the total sum has 18% tip included? Or will this be treated as theft?
Please refer me to the right law that discuss this.

You will probably not be surprised to learn that the dining customs in your home country don't have much bearing on the laws of New York. There probably isn't a "right law" that discusses this specifically. Instead, it's a simple matter of contract law.
Applebee's is allowed to list cheeseburgers at a price of $14. If you order that cheeseburger, you're offering to pay that price. If they bring you the cheeseburger, they have accepted your offer, and you now have a contractual obligation to pay .
Applebee's is allowed to list cheeseburgers at a price of $14 plus an 18 percent gratuity. If you order that cheeseburger, you're offering to pay that price. If they bring you the cheeseburger, they have accepted your offer, and you now have a contractual obligation to pay $14 plus an 18 percent gratuity.
Applebee's is allowed to list cheeseburgers at a price of $14 plus a backrub for the hostess. If you order that cheeseburger, you're offering to pay that price. If they bring you the cheeseburger, they have accepted your offer, and you now have a contractual obligation to pay $14 plus a backrub for the hostess.
If you object to any of those prices, you have two main options:

You are free to not order the cheeseburger.
You are free to attempt to negotiate a different price.

But you are not free to not pay the price you agreed to. If you order but don't pay, it's breach of contract and probably theft.

I didn’t agree to pay that price. I didn’t know there gonna charge me 18% more and they only notified me when I got the bill

@Yotamfreund They also don't notify you of what taxes you are going to pay and how much they are going to be until you pay your bill but you still have to pay those. Unfortunately there are plenty of things that get added on later and you don't know how much you are paying until you get the bill and there isn't much you can do about that.

@JoeW Your assertion that you don't know how much you are paying until you get the bill and there isn't much you can do about that directly contradicts the answer(s) to the duplicate question, as well as common sense (allowing restaurants to set the service charge to 20000% without posting that price beforehand will obviously allow abusive behavior). Care to provide a reference?

@UJM I wasn't just talking about tips, there are things that getting added on the the bill pretty much anywhere you make a purchase that you won't see until you get the bill.

@JoeW What are those things? Taxes can (theoretically) be known beforehand (if the customer is a savvy tax lawyer). Stuff that is at the restaurant’s discretion, surely, must be communicated in advance? I suspect the restaurant must answer truthfully questions about the full price of the meal, and I would not be surprised to learn that the restaurant must disclose that information even if the customer does not specifically ask. That is the law in France, for instance (see articles L112-1 and L112-3 of the consumer code).

@UJM And the same can be said about tips as well. Generally in the US when you look at a price on a menu or price tag it doesn't include any of the taxes or other fees that will be added on at the point of sale. These taxes can be different based on what jurisdiction you are in what taxes apply or don't apply to your purchase. In some areas you can even have places that are in different cities/states that are right across the street from each other.

This answer doesn't address the stated situation where gratuity is advertised in the menu as applicable to parties of 4 or more, yet is added for a party of 2.
